# Tradingview pine-script backtesting rsi

Tags: pine-script, trading

I'm back-testing and RSI(6) strategy. I want it to buy on the SECOND CROSSING of the 30 oversold line(When it is going back up) and Sell on the SECOND CROSSING of the 70 oversold line(when it is going down). I can only get it to buy and sell when it immediately crosses the overbought/oversold line which is not why I'm trying to do. I'm also trying to add a 10% stop loss. Does anyone have any ideas how to implement those orders? This is my code so far.

```
strategy("RSI", overlay = true)

longcon = rsi(close, 6) < 30 

closecon = rsi(close,6) > 70

//backtest from 2015
_year = 2015

strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, when = longcon and year >= _year)

strategy.close("long", when = closecon)

plot(close)
```

Answer (score 0):

This shows debugging plots so you can see the logic unfolding:

```
//@version=4
strategy("RSI")
r = rsi(close, 6)
_year = 2015

bool xUp = crossover(r, 30)
bool xDn = crossunder(r, 70)
var bool firstXUp = false
var bool firstXDn = false
var bool inLong   = false
var bool inShort  = false
var float longStop = na

if xUp
    firstXDn := false
    if firstXUp
        inLong   := true
        inShort  := false
        firstXUp := false
    else if not inLong
        firstXUp := true
else if xDn
    firstXUp := false
    if firstXDn
        inLong   := false
        inShort  := true
        firstXDn := false
    else if inLong
        firstXDn := true
enterLong = inLong  and not inLong[1]
exitLong  = not inLong and inLong[1]
longStop := enterLong ? close * 0.9 : exitLong ? na : longStop

strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, when = enterLong and year >= _year)
strategy.close("long", when = exitLong, comment = "xDn")
strategy.close("long", when = close < longStop, comment = "Stop")

plot(r)
hline(30)
hline(70)

// Debugging
plotchar(xUp, "xUp", "•", location.bottom, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(xDn, "xDn", "•", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(firstXUp, "firstXUp", "1", location.bottom, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(firstXDn, "firstXDn", "1", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(longStop, "longStop", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
bgcolor(inLong ? color.green : an)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the help